# Error creating scratch orgs with "Communities" enabled

Tags: community, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, experience-cloud, experience-bundle

I am following the steps listed here [Build scratch org definition file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) in order to enable communities for a scratch org, but the following error is received:

```
We couldn't find a template with the ID specified in the scratch org definition. If you’re sure the ID is correct, contact Salesforce Support.
```

This is my scratch org definition file:

```
{
"orgName": "Demo",
"edition": "Developer",
"features": ["Communities"],
"settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
        "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true
    }
}
```

}

I can create standard scratch orgs, but for some reason is failing for communities, tried changing the edition to "Enterprise". My sourceApiVersion for this project is 49.0.

I can not find this error in the list of known issues for Scratch Orgs listed here: [Scratch Org Error Codes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_error_codes.htm). Hoping to find answers here before contacting support. Thanks!

Comment: Looks related to ongoing known issue  https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=scratch-org-creation-getting-failed-with-an-error-error-running-force-org-create-we-couldn-t-find-a-template-with-the-id-specified-in-the-scratch&Id=a1p4V000001aEAX .Try workaround of using "release": "Previous" in your project-scratch-def.json and confirm if that works for you.Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Swetha, the work around worked.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @Alex. I have posted this information as an answer so it might help others too

Comment: We see this problem with a non-Communities scratch org definition too.

Comment: @KeithC checking…

Comment: Thanks @Swetha. Bit more info here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346489/scratch-org-creation-if-failing-with-these-2-symptoms-today-why.

Comment: I have confirmed that the bug impacts all default 232(Summer'21) scratch org creation. The fix for the known issue will respect this scenario too. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you are facing is related to ongoing [Known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=scratch-org-creation-getting-failed-with-an-error-error-running-force-org-create-we-couldn-t-find-a-template-with-the-id-specified-in-the-scratch&Id=a1p4V000001aEAX). Our Salesforce Team is working to fix it.

The workaround would be to switch to previous release by using "release": "Previous" in your project-scratch-def.json so that it would enforce the scratch org creation in previous release for time being.

Example

```
{
    "orgName": "MyCompany",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "release": "Previous",
    "features": ["Communities", "ServiceCloud", "Chatbot"],
    "settings": {
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true
        }
    },
    "objectSettings": {
        "task": {
            "defaultRecordType": "default"
        }
    }
}
```

Or use

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a myPrevious -v acmDevHub -d 30 release=Previous
```

**UPDATE**: The issue has been fixed for all the affected orgs and known issue has been updated to reflect the same

Comment: Is this still on-going?

Comment: @PhilW The issue is resolved and the fix has been rolled out already. I will update my answer to reflect the same. Thank you