# Scratch org creation if failing with these 2 symptoms today - why?

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, dev-hub

The failures are occurring for both our Continuous Integration (CI) builds and out interactive creates. The CI output is:

> Run sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a
> scratch-org -s -d 1
>
> ERROR running force:org:create:  We couldn't find
> a template with the ID specified in the scratch org definition. If
> you’re sure the ID is correct, contact Salesforce Support.
>
> Error:
> Process completed with exit code 1.

and when I look at the corresponding Scratch Org Info records I see:

- Status: Error
- Error Code: C-1020

The scratch def is:

```
{
  "orgName": "MyOrg",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "language": "en_US",
  "features": ["SharedActivities"],
  "settings": {
    "opportunitySettings": {
      "enableOpportunityTeam": true
    },
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

I've found nothing useful Googling both:

- We couldn't find a template with the ID specified in the scratch org definition.
- C-1020

**PS**

Found the C-1020 here in [SignupRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_signuprequest.htm) documentation:

- C-1020: Template not found. Either the template doesn't exist (or it was deleted).

Comment: It's an ongoing issue (affecting us too) - see the linked Known Issue on the question above.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed very helpful. Note not a Communities org in this case.

Comment: Yeah, the Communities thing is a red herring. I believe the scope is orgs on a 232 pod but don't quote me on that :)

Comment: I have confirmed that the bug impacts *all* default 232 scratch org creation. The fix for the known issue will respect this scenario too. Thank you